# Move semantics in parameter passing

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have following test example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void foo (std::vector<int> value) {
  std::cout << "value  "
            << &value
            << " "
            << value.data()
            << " "
            << value.size()
            << std::endl;
}

void foo2 (std::vector<int>&& rvalure_ref) {
  std::cout << "rvalue_ref  "
            << &rvalure_ref
            << " "
            << rvalure_ref.data()
            << " "
            << rvalure_ref.size()
            << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> value(5, 0);
  std::cout << "init "
            << &value
            << " "
            << value.data()
            << " "
            << value.size()
            << std::endl;
  
  foo(std::move(value));
  
  
  std::cout << "done "
            << &value
            << " "
            << value.data()
            << " "
            << value.size()
            << std::endl;
}
```

The result of the code above is:

```
init 0x7ffed27c6450 0x56480bc1eeb0 5
value  0x7ffed27c6470 0x56480bc1eeb0 5
done 0x7ffed27c6450 0 0
```

Looks great:

Now, move to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void foo (std::vector<int> value) {
  std::cout << "value  "
            << &value
            << " "
            << value.data()
            << " "
            << value.size()
            << std::endl;
}

void foo2 (std::vector<int>&& rvalure_ref) {
  std::cout << "rvalue_ref  "
            << &rvalure_ref
            << " "
            << rvalure_ref.data()
            << " "
            << rvalure_ref.size()
            << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> value(5, 0);
  std::cout << "init "
            << &value
            << " "
            << value.data()
            << " "
            << value.size()
            << std::endl;
  
  foo2(std::move(value));
  
  
  std::cout << "done "
            << &value
            << " "
            << value.data()
            << " "
            << value.size()
            << std::endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
init 0x7ffccc93a5c0 0x56124b3a8eb0 5
rvalue_ref  0x7ffccc93a5c0 0x56124b3a8eb0 5
done 0x7ffccc93a5c0 0x56124b3a8eb0 5
```

My problem is:

For the 1st case, it is perfectly called by "move semantics", and as you see, the ownership of the vector has been transfered to the function parameter. Finally, at "done", the data is null to verify the the vector at main() no longer owns the vector.

Now to explicitly claim the parameter is "rvalue reference", as case 2. As you see, actually it is like "call by (l)reference".

How can I figure out it?

Comment: Despite the name, `std::move` doesn't actually move anything. It's merely a convenient way to write a cast to rvalue reference, which allows its result to be moved from. It's the code that uses this reference that may or may not actually move. `foo` does so move, but `foo2` does not - it takes its argument by reference, and works directly on that argument, without any attempt to copy it or move from it. If you want `foo2` to take ownership of the data, then move the argument into some `vector` instance.

Comment: To be more specific, the thing that actually was moving in `foo` was the move constructor that constructed `value` from `std::move(value)` (and I wish you'd used different names for those variables to make discussing them easier). The move constructor is what zeroed out the `value` in `main`, not the `std::move` itself.